# Python Pandas: How to split a column on parenthesis from a column of dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a pandas data frame:

```
In [8]: test
 Out[8]: 
           Product           Price
0      Berlin Stret (E10)     12
1      Paris Ave (C12)        34
2      5th Ave (D30)          56
```

I am trying to split the column product in 2 columns such as

```
       Product      Room  Price
 0   Berlin Stret    E10   12
 1   Paris Ave       C12   34
 2   5th Ave         D30   56
```

I tried to use

```
df['Product'], df['Room'] = df['Product'].str.split('()', 1).str
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex with `extract`:

```
df[['product','room']]= df.Product.str.extract('(.)\s\((.\d+)', expand=True)
```

Output (lower case product new column):

```
   Product  Price product room
0  A (E10)     12       A  E10
1  B (C12)     34       B  C12
2  C (D30)     56       C  D30
```

Or use regex '|' with split:

```
df[['product','room']] = df.Product.str.split('\(|\)', expand=True).iloc[:,[0,1]]
```

Output:

```
   Product  Price product room
0  A (E10)     12      A   E10
1  B (C12)     34      B   C12
2  C (D30)     56      C   D30
```

Comment: Yes it works with letters: what if I have `df['Product'][0] = 'Berlin Street (E10)'` and I want to separate the columns in `'Berlin Street' 'E10'`?

Comment: The second method should still work, the first one you may need to add '+' after the first '.'.